# restrict occurences of a div with class="a" under a div class="b" to 5 in jquery slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div id="b" class="b">
 <c:forEach items="${listitems}" var="item">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
 </c:forEach>
</div>
```

div with class="a" will iterate 10 times, but i want to dynamically show 5 or 6 occurances only,using java script. anybody know how to do this with jquery?

Comment: what do you mean by 5 or 6... is there a logic behind it

Comment: i got a list of <div class="a"> , and actually i want to show only a 5 no.of <div class="a">

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can make use of slice with `class="a"` div inside `class="b"` div selector as shown below.

```
$(function(){
  $('div.b div.a').slice(0,5); // will show only first 5 divs with class=a
});
```

**[For more information on Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)**

Comment: happy to help you :). You can accept this answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a css rule to do that like

```
#b .a:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#b .a:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="b" class="b">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">${item.val1}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val2}</div>
    <div class="c">${item.val3}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```